# libopenal.so.1 versus libopenal.so.0

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, openal

I have a report from a steam reviewer that couldn't launch the 64bit Linux binary for my game.

My game was built on Ubuntu LTS, and has these dependencies:

```
$ readelf -d Hexa 

Dynamic section at offset 0x2c0880 contains 34 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libdl.so.2]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [librt.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libopenal.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libGL.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libsteam_api.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
...
```

The reviewer mentioned that **libopenal.so.1** failed to be located.

I was expecting that every Linux distribution would come with libopenal.so.1 but is that correct?

Now I am thinking, maybe some systems are still on libopenal.so.0 perhaps?

How would I properly release a linux binary that depends on libopenal?

Under what circumstances would I find a system without libopenal.so.1?

Is libopenal.so.0 something that is out there, in the wild?

Comment: I'm not sure I would agree with *"every Linux distribution would come with libopenal.so"*. That is a lot of distros. You should probably state the platform so folks can comment on the problem at hand. For example, `libopenal.so` is installed on my Ubuntu 18/Bionic workstation (maybe because SuperTux is installed). But `libopenal.so` is not installed on my Ubuntu 19/Disco, Fedora 30 or GNU Hurd workstations. I'm not sure what Arch Linux and Linux From Scratch are doing.

Comment: Ok, I will rephrase.. every linux machine that is running Valve's Steam client, will come with openal. Why would you run steam on your machine, but not openal? At least half the steam games use openal for sound.